# How would I find a variable in a line and use cut to retrieve the value

Tags: unix

The problem is essentially this, I need to be able to search for a variable within a a line that I have already cat'ed out from /proc/cmdline.  Then be able to cut the value of this variable out (in this case I want to cut out the value of Disktype).

*It should be noted that this will be in the PXE boot environment so most other language tools won't be available and the variable and value can differ in where it appears in /proc/cmdline.

So essentially If I cat out /proc/cmdline I could get this:

```
centos-workstation-x86_64/vmlinuz initrd=centos-workstation-x86_64/initrd.img locale=en_US Disktype=Fresh
```

or this

```
rhel6-workstation-x86_64/vmlinuz initrd=rhel6-workstation-x86_64/initrd.img Disktype=Large locale=en_US
```

or any other variation with even more other variables set up for PXE.

*clarification this will be part of a larger kickstart file

** For those that may wonder why this might be useful,  using this I will be specifying later a case statement in the kickstart that matches what was thrown into Disktype to determine what partition.cfg to use during the installation process.

Comment: So, are you looking for a specific variable, any one of a set, or something else?  Instead of `cut` have you considered using `awk`, it is really better suited to this.

Comment: I hadn't thought about using awk yet.  Do you have a solution in mind with utilizing awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `awk` it's easy if you correctly set th **Record Separator** and **Field Separator**:

```
awk  '/Disktype/{print $2}' RS=" " FS==
```

`cut` doesn't really lend itself to this task:

```
tr " " "\n" | grep Disktype | cut -f 2 -d =
```

You could also do it using `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^.*Disktype=\([^ ]\+\)/\1/p'
```